# Difference between oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_CALL vs oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_SESSION

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, ojdbc

oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_CALL vs oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_SESSION

What is the difference between the two?

> It is used to create a temporary LOB by calling the
>   BLOB.createTemporary(connection, true, flag).

I have the following scenario:

> All connections are pooled and never released till shutdown. I want the
>   temporary LOB to be in existence only for a execution of
>   preparedStatement (viz for insert. After insert, I don't need the lob).
>   Which flag should I use?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `DURATION_SESSION` is more suitable in this case.

Some links:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10979/oralob.htm#i1060097

http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/constant-values.html#oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_CALL

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96591/adl11tmp.htm